# django-storages + private S3 bucket - How can I make a username the folder name?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-models, boto3, python-django-storages

I'm using django-storages and a private S3 bucket to store user uploads. I would like the following folder structure:

```
/uploads/someuser321/20190112-123456/
```

I obviously know how to do the timestamp (2019-01-12 at 12:34:56), but how do I get the user's username into the path? My model currently looks like this:

```
user_file = models.FileField(
    upload_to="uploads", 
    storage=PrivateMediaStorage(), 
    null=True, blank=True)
```

I can just add an f-string for the datetime/timestamp. I understand that and I know how to do it. But how can I add the user's username as a folder as well? I would need to somehow access this from the view, so that I know who the request.user is, but how would I even do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a function call inside upload_to. Here's a function that will get you the path:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    today = localtime(now()).date()
    return '{0}/uploads/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.user.username, today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), filename)
```

Then you need to call it like this inside your model:

```
user_file = models.FileField(
    upload_to=get_file_path, 
    storage=PrivateMediaStorage(), 
    null=True, blank=True)
```

You need to fix that return statement to get the desired format, but that will do it. Django will automatically pass an instance to your function and the filename.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Oh this is beautiful. I just had to adapt it to my model and it worked straight away. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Will this prevent from accessing file for another user id? Will this handle it automatically?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there @ViktorVostrikov. This code is basically generating the path which will include username, so that every user can have their own folder. It doesn't have anything do with access. You need to handle that inside the view when accessing files.

Comment: But, if I don't add any protections, then users can guess/bruteforce my file path of the S3 and download other users' files. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov I got this code from my project which uses local storage.I have a protected folder in Nginx and to get the file the user goes through a view which checks their permissions and sends X-Access header to Nginx instructing it to serve the file. But with S3 you need to generate a signed URL via boto. However, it seems that django-storages abstracts this for you. See this https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/770332b598712da27ecdba75c9e202ad6a1a8722/storages/backends/s3boto3.py#L554